# Wordpress Domain name appending on all links as shown on ANALYTICS and SEM RUSH

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console, domains, wordpress

I need your help. For some reason Google Analytics is showing that our page views all went to URLS that end with our appending URL again in the end.

Our website is in wordpress and uses SEO Yoast Plugin. We had been using it without problem for 3-4 months, working on our SEO little by little and gotten really good results and this month all of a sudden this starts to happen. It nw only is making our ranking go down steeply, but from the Analytics report im thinking that any of the users we managed to get through SEO efforts this month were directed to error/404 pages.

[image: Google Analytics results showing URL landing pages with the appending URL at the end]

This is also showing on our SEM Rush results.

[image: SEM RUSH results showing URL landing pages with the appending URL at the end]

Search Console does not find these errors.

[image: Search Console reports no errors in 90 days]

I don't understand why this is happening or how/when it began. But our SEO ranking (which we are doing ourselves) is suffering badly because of it and I cant figure out how to fix it.

[image: SEM RUSH SEO Ranking results show a steep decline in the last few weeks]

PLEASE PLEASE if any of you know what is going on and how we can fix this it would be GREATLY APPRECIATED.

Thank you so so much in advance for any help given.
Mabel

Comment: Did you ever put a filter in your Google Analytics to show the full domain?  [View Full Page URL In Reports - Analytics Help](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012243?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing happens if you add something to you default page in the View Settings. It should be blank.